# Should we remove function documentation from code blocks?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, etiquette, code-formatting

I don't have an example, but I have come across some code blocks from new people that contain documentation in their code sample. For *example*:

```
/// <summary>
/// TCP protocol handler
/// </summary>
class TCPProtocol
```

These comments are generally useless as any person who calls themselves a programmer should be able to interpret what's class does by its functions and what a function does by its name and source.

Now, I'm not saying documentation is bad, but I am saying that documentation is not needed when you have the function **right there** on the page. All they do is add clutter an make reading the code harder.

Now, I'm not suggesting we [bite the new users](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Please_do_not_bite_the_newcomers), but I am asking if we should remove documentation from code blocks should we encounter it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends:

If the comment really helps (it explains *why* instead of what), and it adds value to the question by being there, then it's a good comment and should stay.

If the comment is, as you suggested above, just a recap of what the method is named, then remove it.

There are a few reasons:

- Easier to read questions are more likely to be voted up
- Documentation comments make the post longer than it needs to be without adding the value that justifies that length
- code samples should be short, self contained, and complete, and the presence of a documentation comment negates that

Or, as I like to remember :

> "Perfection is finally attained not when there is no longer anything to add but when there is no longer anything to take away." - Antoine de Saint-Exupery ([Source](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/antoinedes401881.html#8plF2miyYCaoycU7.99))

Answer (score 11):

> *"any person who calls themselves a programmer should be able to interpret what's class does by its functions and what a function does by its name and source."*

Ah, if only everyone would be so kind to properly name their classes, functions and variables, making their bare code easier to read.

I would say that it does no harm and would leave it in. An exception might be in the case where it's overly long, meaning I would have to scroll a page even before seeing the actual code. Then I might (and I mean might) edit it out because it would form a distraction.

But other than that I would welcome some clear and well-documented code.

Answer (score 5):

I feel it should be kept there. For one, generally we don't edit others' code on SO.

Secondly, sometimes there is a lot of code. You only want to understand part of it to answer the question, so a summary of the rest is pretty handy.  It takes time to understand a function. Understanding a summary is quick.

Plus, what's the harm? Clutter isn't that much of a problem.

Comment: Try on a mobile phone, and you'll have a different opinion of "clutter".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I used to use mobile regularly (not anymore because I don't have wifi where I am). But I've never had much of a problem skipping through clutter if it's in one place.