# Somebody actually approved this edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits

It's bad enough when somebody tries to "fix" the code in an answer, or worse, an accepted answer.  But, is there any doubt that this suggested edit is completely improper?  The user couldn't post a comment, so they appended it with a ranting rebuttal...

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1507293

Yet a member with enough rep to know better, apparently doesn't know any better at all.

Should the amount of rep required to review answer edits be increased to the 5K or 7.5K level? This is half-joking, but perhaps make people pass a quiz before being allowed to review edit suggestions.  Edit:  Or users with enormously large approve/reject ratios should be reviewed and have their privileges suspended.

Comment: And [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1507200) (but this one was a 10k user).

Comment: Nah, suggested-edit-approval voting. Get enough downvotes in a certain timeframe and you get banned; forever.

Comment: Note how much rep the user has in animuson's example.  Rep simply isn't a good enough indicator of the quality of the reviewer, increasing it might help a bit, but not a lot.

Comment: @Servy, yes, I see his point.  I just get discouraged when I see the content of answers defaced and then subsequently approved.

Comment: @Sparky As a general rule I can't spend more than 5 minutes in the /review system without getting discouraged in some way, shape, or form.

Comment: If you notice the lone approver has reviewed 100 edits and only 2 rejects.  And I thought my 2-to-1 accept to reject ratio was high.

Comment: @Servy, lol... yes, for that reason, I find myself spending less and less time reviewing.

Comment: @Sparky Same here.

Comment: Maybe users with an enormous approval to reject ratio should have their review privileges reviewed and suspended.

Comment: @just went to check my approve/reject ratio and found that I have 666 approvals.

Comment: I suspect AppDeveloper didn't [even it read it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qP7RC.png)

Comment: When you think about it, it's kinda weird that we allow answers to be edited in the first place.  They need to stand on their own, code mistakes, dead links, bad grammar and all... just let the voting system take care of them.

Comment: Oooh, ooh, is this finally the thread where we post bad edits we've been collecting to shame the approvers? <Gets out my file...>

Comment: I'd also be in favor of bringing back the **Strunk & White** badge requirement for reviewing suggested edits. I mean, if the user has only made 5 edits themselves, they certainly don't seem very qualified to be voting on other edits.

Comment: That user has been in my hit list for a good couple of weeks.

Comment: @Sparky - people with all levels of reputation apparently have [bad days](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1416967#./1416967?&_suid=13606997694060006727917446748832) when reviewing

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Well, that reviewer has over a 6:1 approval:rejection ratio, which is worrisome to me...

Comment: I've make hundreds or thousands of edits on questions... but very rarely do I touch somebody else's answer... and when I have, it was to fix something minor like unformatted code or a bad URL.  Does interference with voting (others' rep) by editing answers really make this place better?

Comment: @Sparky It's a bit offtopic, but you may be interested in [this recent question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167260/should-we-reject-additions-of-a-description-on-a-code-only-answer/167273#167273)

Comment: @animuson I've actually suggested that as a solution to the review problem [previously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157745/182513)

Comment: I've seen this kind of "editing in a lengthy response" behavior before, always by an anonymous users, and it makes me think that it should be impossible for anonymous users to edit.

Comment: I don't know that we need to call out every instance of this. [The new suggested edit audit mechanism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159544/why-no-honeypot-suggested-edits/165489#165489) is rapidly taking care of the worst offenders, and if people are rubber-stamping edits like this they soon will be banned from the queue. I've been watching this and it really does seem to be making a difference.

Comment: @BradLarson, that's really good to know.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I've seen non-anon users doing the same thing, but I do agree that I've seen very, very few anon edits worthy of approval, so I question the need for that feature to be there.

Comment: @BradLarson Could you do a query to see the approval rate of edits from anonymous users, I'm curious what it is.

Comment: @BradLarson: our thirst for the blood of the offenders will not be quenched until their usercards scroll by on some sort of audit-ban mugshots page. Only then will we feel better about what the edit queue has become....

Comment: @Servy - You might have to hand-tally these yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits?filter=month&tab=anonymous , but when I commented here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140935/lots-of-vandalism-by-anonymous-edit-suggestions#comment398631_140935 there was a 37% approval rate for anonymous edits.

Comment: **We will not rest until a *Registered audit offender* badge is placed underneath those users' Gravatars!** Seriously though, this is terrible and totally worthwhile calling out when it happens IMO. Could a second layer of audits not help here? It would at least reduce the probability of a bad audit coming through *massively*.

Comment: @Servy - OK, looks like 39% approval rate all-time from this Data Explorer query: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60664/breakdown-of-anonymously-suggested-edits

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for the links.

Comment: @Servy you can query the SuggestedEditVotes. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142221/148672

Comment: That question needs to be deleted.

Comment: I saw someone suggesting edit to **tag wiki** where he asked a question. **IT GOT APPROVED**. [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1258733). Think that's an unbreakable record and the best part is that we have no roll back for tag wiki.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - now **that** is specal.  "improved formatting" indeed!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Approved by 3 to 1 no less!

Comment: @Pekka웃 - it can be the Scarlet R!  the Red Badge of Shame!  Boy, this thread has been kinda cathartic.